# Validation Existing Data with Create and Edit Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

---

I'm a beginner programming ASP.NET and MVC. I have a question (my title).
Firstly, I built Create action. Follow the link:
http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/check-instantly-if-username-exists-asp-net-mvc-remote-validation.

But in that way, my edit action will check and get error about Existing Data. 
My question is how to skip Check existing data while I work with Edit Action.
Thanks for help.

Comment: take another parameter for action name and if it is edit then don't check in db

Comment: @Ehsan how will it solve the issue?
Model consist
`[Remote("doesUserNameExist", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.")]` for UserName and where ever the Model will be called the JSON Action to check user name will be fired.

This is used when user has no right to edit his credentials once entered while registration.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from the model:

`[Remote("doesUserNameExist", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.")]`

**AJAX Method:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnCheck").click(function() {
    var name = $("#UserName").val(); //Value entered in the text box
    var status = $("#divStatus"); //DIV object to display the status message
    status.html("Checking....") //While our Thread works, we will show some message to indicate the progress

    //jQuery AJAX Post request
    $.post("/Account/doesUserNameExist", { username: name },
        function(data) {
            if (data == "true") {
                status.html(name + " is available!");
            } else {
                status.html(name + " is not available!");
            }
        });
});
});
```

Model consist
`[Remote("doesUserNameExist", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.")]` for UserName and where ever the Model will be called the JSON Action to check user name will be fired.

This is used when user has no right to edit his credentials once entered while registration.

Comment: You can't do this. My Create Action have to check exist Username. Have any ideal?

Comment: yes, for that you can use a javascript which will ensure that Check User will only be checked while creating and not editing

Comment: If you will mention the Check function in the model, then it will check every time you will call the model

Comment: use AJAX to call the action

Comment: I saw your comment. Thanks you

Comment: It's OK. Thanks again for your enthusiasm